# Pycharm community edition wont stop on breakpoints inside parallel code

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, multiprocessing

I am trying to debug a multiprocessing function with PyCharm community edition. The debugger seems to stop in the forked process but i cant explore any variables in the debugger view. I only see this:
[image]
And in the console I see this outputs:
[image]

Seems like when a breakpoint is reached in a forked process this gets printed: `Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.`
Debugger for single threadded code works normaly as exected.

System Info:

```
PyCharm 2020.2.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-202.8194.22, built on December 1, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.9+11-b944.49 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.10.2-2-manjaro
Current Desktop: i3
```

Minimal code that reproducess the problem:

```
def func(x):
    # Breakpoint here
    return x*x

a = [1,2,3,4]
p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
p.map(func,a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got resolved with the latest PyCharm update and `pacman -Syu`